# How to find out what changes on a branch after merges from master?

Tags: git, branch, diff

I forked `master` for a branch.  From time to time I merge `master` into my branch for updates.

```
       /--B--D--G--H--J--L--M--> dev (HEAD)
      /        /     /
-----A--C--E--F--I--K---> master
```

How can I show the changes only on my branch, excluding those from the merges?
I.e. show difference only on commits `B`, `D`, `H`, `L`, `M`.

`git diff A` doesn't work because it includes merged changes from `master`.

BTW, I will appreciate if anyone knows a quick way to find `A` without keep scrolling down the log.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not clear to me precisely what you're looking for.  But note that:

- Commits store snapshots.  This means that commit `K` has a complete source tree that is independent of whatever is in commits `A`, `B`, `C`, and so on.  Likewise, commit `J` has a complete snapshot, independent of whatever is in `A`, or `K`, or any other commit.

  (The word "independent" here means that if you ask Git to retrieve commit `J`, it would not matter if you had somehow managed to alter commit `K` after making `J`.  It's not actually *possible* to alter any commit, ever; `git commit --amend` *seems* to change a commit, but really does not.)
- Using `git diff` on two specific commits, Git extracts each of the two snapshots, and compares those.

#### Simple diffs

Therefore, `git diff K M` will show you what is different between the current tip of `master` (commit `K`), and the current tip of `dev` (commit `M`).

You can also just spell this `git diff master dev`.

That may be what you want to see (again, it's not really clear to me).  So **answer 1: `git diff master dev`.**

#### Multiple independent diffs

On the other hand, maybe what you want is to show one diff for commit `B`, one diff for commit `D`, one diff for commit `H`, one diff for commit `L`, and one diff for commit `M`.  That is, you want to see each non-merge commit, one at a time, as compared to its (single) parent.

You could `git diff A B`, and `git diff B D`, and so on.  But you can also just `git show B`, and `git show D`, and so on.  This shows you the commit as a change, instead of as a snapshot.

You may be wondering how this is possible if commits store snapshots, rather than changes.  (This trips a lot of people up since most *other* Version Control Systems actually do store changes.)  The answer to this apparent contradiction is that `git show` looks up the same graph you drew.

Look again at commit `B`.  What commit comes before it?  That is, which commit is to its left, following lines leftwards?  There's only one possible ancestor for commit `B`, and that's its single parent, commit `A`.  So `git show B`:

1. extracts the snapshot for commit `A`, then
2. extracts the snapshot for commit `B`, then
3. diffs those two snapshots.

Similarly, there's only one immediate ancestor (parent) for commit `M`, and that's commit `L`.  So `git show M`:

1. extracts the snapshot for `L`, then
2. extracts the snapshot for `M`, then
3. diffs those two snapshots.

If this is what you want, the interesting question becomes: *how do you find the IDs of each commit in the `B`, `D`, `H`, `L`, and `M` sequence*?  The answer to this is a bit complicated, but the key command is `git rev-list`, which is essentially the same command as `git log`.  What these commands (`git log` and `git rev-list` both) do is to *walk the commit graph*.  That is, you pick some starting point—in this case, commit `M`, the tip of `dev`—and tell Git to walk backwards through the commits, looking at each commit's parents.

The problem is that when you hit a merge commit, such as commit `J`, Git walks back to *all* of its parents.  You want to restrict Git to finding only the parent that was the tip of branch `dev` when you made the merge commit.  Git has a flag for this, spelled `--first-parent`.  This tells `git rev-list` to follow only the *first* parent of each merge commit.

We also want to skip the merges, so we can add `--no-merges` (this does not affect the walking-back process, it just limits the printed revision IDs to exclude the merges).

This leads to **answer 2a: `git rev-list --first-parent --no-merges ^A dev`** (we'll get to the "not A" part later).

Now, actually using this with `git rev-list` is kind of a pain, because now we have to take each commit ID and then run `git show` on it.  There's a much easier way, though, because *`git rev-list` and `git log` are essentially the same command*, and `git log -p` shows each commit as a *patch*, doing much the same thing as `git show`.

This leads to **answer 2b: `git log -p --first-parent --no-merges ^A dev`**.  We don't necessarily need the `--no-merges` here either; see below.

#### Merge commits and combined diffs

The one special thing that `git show` does, that `git diff` doesn't, is to handle the case of showing a *merge* commit, such as commit `J`.  Commit `J` has *two* parents, namely commits `H` and `K` (incidentally, this implies that you made commit `K` before making commit `J` :-) ).  If you run `git diff H J`, Git will extract the snapshots for `H` and `J` and compare them.  If you run `git diff K J`, Git will extract the snapshots for `K` and `J` and compare them.  But if you run `git show J`, Git will:

1. extract the snapshot for `H`, then
2. extract the snapshot for `K`, then
3. extract the snapshot for `J` (the merge), and finally
4. produce what Git calls a *combined diff*.

The combined diff from step 4 attempts to show, in a compact fashion, changes from both `H` *and* `K` to `J`.  In compacting the changes, Git *throws out* any file where the version in either `H` *or* `K` matches the version in `J`.

That is, suppose file `README.txt` has some change from `H` to `J`.  But suppose that `README.txt` is the *same* in `K` and `J`.  In other words, when you did the `git merge`, you were picking up changes from `K` in order to make `J`, and there were no changes to `README.txt` from the other side of the merge.  This means `README.txt` exactly matches one "incoming side", and hence the combined diff *completely ignores the file*.

This means combined diffs often show nothing at all, even though the merge picked up some change(s) in the new snapshot.  To see those changes, you must make *two* diffs, not just one.  You must make one diff from `H` to `J`, and another diff from `K` to `J`, rather than relying on the combined diff.

When using `git log -p`, you can also see combined diffs for merges, by adding `-c` or `--cc` to the options.  But if you *don't* ask for this, what Git does is actually laughably simple: *it just doesn't bother to show a diff at all*.

So this leads to **answer 2c: `git log -p --first-parent ^A dev`**.  All we did is drop the `--no-merges`: we will now see each merge's *log message*, but no diff.

#### What is this `^A` thing?

This also ties into your other question:

> BTW, I will appreciate if anyone knows a quick way to find A without keep scrolling down the log.

The answer to this is to make a *symbolic name* for commit `A`.  Find its ID once and then choose a name, like `dev` or `master` (but don't use either those since those are in use!).

That's all `dev` and `master` *are*: they're just symbolic names for commits, plus the extra property that, as branch names, you can `git checkout` the symbolic name and wind up "on" the branch.  You can give `A` a branch-name too.  You will need to make sure you do not `git checkout` this branch and make commits on it, because if you do that, you'll grow a new branch, rather than just leaving the branch-name pointing to commit `A`.

Alternatively, you can make a tag-name pointing to commit `A`.  That's almost exactly the same as a branch name.  The two differences are:

1. It's a tag name: you can't check it out as a branch, and therefore can't change it accidentally.
2. It's a tag name: if you `git push --tags` you'll send it upstream as a tag, and then everyone else will have it too.

In this case point 1 is in your favor and point 2 is probably not, so it's up to you whether the advantage (can't accidentally change it) is worth the risk (might accidentally publish it).

If you have the ID of `A`, then, you can:

```
$ git tag A <id-of-commit-A>
```

and now you have the *name* `A`.  (You can later `git tag -d A` to delete it, although if you accidentally published it, you'll probably keep getting it back from your upstream.)

Getting back to the question of the `^A` string in the `git log` commands, all `^A` does is tell `git rev-list` (and therefore `git log`) to *stop* walking through the commit graph upon reaching commit `A`.  The commit is also not shown (for `git rev-list`, not printed; for `git log`, not shown in the log output).  The prefix `^` symbol is short for "not", i.e., "get me all commits reachable from `dev`, but *not* reachable from `A`".  Adding `--first-parent` makes Git traverse only the *first* parent of each merge, so that we do not walk into commits merged from `master`.

(The `^A dev` syntax can also be spelled `A..dev`.  Note that this works with both `git log` and `git rev-list`, but means something very different for `git diff`.)

Comment: aarr... I misunderstood how 'diff' work and presumed 'git diff master' would return L and M only.  Thanks for the thorough explanation and covering all possible cases of my question.  Those are informative.

Comment: So actually I don't need the second part anymore.  And a tag would work.  As a note, I was wondering if there was a command like 'git branch-origin dev' that could give me the commit A...

Comment: @kc2: Git does not store the origination point of a branch. (I think the Git folks' primary reason for this is a firm belief that attempting to do so means you're using Git wrong, and their secondary one is because it's technically difficult, but maybe it's the other order. :-) The branch name's reflog does store the creation event, until that reflog entry expires, so *if the creation event is still there*, you can get a hash from it.)