# git - find files changed in branch, since created

Tags: git, version-control

I would like to get a list of files which were changed in branch, since branch was created.

Example:

- create branch B1
- commit change in file_1
- commit change in file_2

Result should be: file_1 file_2

How to do that?

I'm NOT interested in difference between Master and B1.

I'm interested in difference between current state of B1 and primary state of B1.

Thanks for responses

Comment: You could just diff between the first commit and the last ? Get the first commit via git log master..branch --oneline | tail -1 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407526/git-how-to-find-first-commit-of-specific-branch)

Comment: Thank you for response. What is first commit? Is it branching operation? Because if first commit is commit that i made on branch making commit. Then I suppose i loose change from first commit. In mine example, the result would be file_2, or i'm wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate (but maybe not, but definitely suggested reading): http://stackoverflow.com/q/39837542/1256452

Answer (score 0):

First, find the diverge point using

```
git merge-base master b1
```

Then use

```
git diff --stat <commit-id>..b1
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I've used git diff as you wrote but it returns me nothing. I tried also git diff --stat master..b1 - it worked. Why? :(